# SQL - Function to get next due date (or past due date)

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2, scheduler

I have read several articles on dates and schedules in SQL, but the solution to my problem continues to elude me.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 r2.

I need to be able to provide the user with a next due date (even if it's in the past). The user is able to create a schedule for importing some data by specifying the frequency (daily, weekly, monthly), a "multiplier" (i.e. every 3 days, every 2 weeks,  every 6 months, etc...) and a start date.

So, my data looks something like this:

```
Frequency | Multiplier | Start date
Weekly    | 2          | 02/15/2012
Monthly   | 1          | 03/01/2012
```

The first record would be scheduling an import every 2 weeks starting on 2/15/2012
The second record would be every month on the 1st (could be a problem if they pick the 31st, haven't addressed that yet).

I also have the last import date, which may or may not have been on time.
So, I want to write a function where I can pass in the frequency (weekly, daily, etc...), the multiplier, and the last import date, and calculate when the next "due" date is after the last import date.

So, given record 1 above (Import every 2 weeks starting on 2/15/2012),  If I have a last import date of 3/1/2012, I would need to return 3/14/2012. Obviously, given that today is the 22nd, this date would be past due and I could mark it as such in any UI that uses this data.  If my last import date is 3/22/2012, I would return 3/28/2012 as the next due date, and so on.
I will probably need to break out the different frequencies (day, week, month) to three functions in order to simplify the logic.

I've looked into a Calendar table [as described here.](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

However, if the solution is there, I'm not sure what it is exactly. I feel very close to a solution, but just haven't yet got it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Thanks for the edit Sam. Looks much better.

Comment: You better provide a few illustration sample data and expected results so that everyone can understand easily and find better solution.

Comment: Thit, please see the third paragraph after the table for illustration and expected reslults. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to pass in the start date as well as the other parameters - since as you say, the last import date may not have fallen on the correct boundary date.

Comment: Can imports be early? And if so how can you tell that `3/22/2012` isn't early for `3/28` rather than late for `3/14`

Comment: Good point Conrad. Obviously I hadn't thought it through enough. Perhaps if I add a "NextDue" date field to the table, and increment it as they upload. That makes sense. I'll have to think through it and see if that poses any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (allowing for late imports): Assuming your schedule table has an ID field, try:

```
;with cte as (
select 0 n, [Start date] as ScheduleDate, [Frequency], [Multiplier] 
from ScheduleTable where [ID] = @ScheduleID
union all
select n+1 n,
       case [Frequency]
            when 'Weekly' then dateadd(Week, [Multiplier], ScheduleDate)
            when 'Daily' then dateadd(Day, [Multiplier], ScheduleDate)
            when 'Yearly' then dateadd(Year, [Multiplier], ScheduleDate)
            ...
       end as ScheduleDate,
       [Frequency], 
       [Multiplier] 
from cte
where n < 32767 and ScheduleDate <= @LastImportDate)
select max(ScheduleDate) as NextDueDate from CTE
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple. The lastImportDate may not match up with the last due date. It may have been imported 3 days late, 2 days early, etc...

Comment: @ Mark Bannister: Interesting... I never thought of doing that. I'll adjust it to my schema and see what I get and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Great Solution for my given requirements. Thank you. Marking as answer. However, Conrad Frix mentioned a scenario that I will have to address; "What if they upload 3 days early... my current solution will still show the current due date (4 days later) as past due. I think I have an idea for it though. Thanks again.